# Can I damage LM723 if I apply 1.2V on the inverting input, when it is not powered?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I'm making a AGM battery charger for a UPS. I need 13.7V with 1A limitation. My schematics needs a diode on the output for reverse protection. But if I take the negative feedback before the diode, as would be normal, my voltage will no loger be stabilized. So I thought of including the diode in the reaction loop. I made the circuit and it works well. But now, the problem is the small voltage (1.2V) which still remains on the non-inverting input of the IC when the supply voltage (V1) is interrupted and the battery is fully charged. Do you thing someting bad can happen with the IC in this case ? This small voltage is limited in current by a 12K resistor.

[image]

Comment: please refer to the LM723 datasheet ... there may be an internal schematic diagram

Comment: Is D3 the wrong way around? Seems you would just have V1 minus the diode drop on the output.

Comment: @GodJihyo , only the battery voltage is regulated. The load voltage can be higher.

Comment: @GodJihyo No, it's ok. When it is powered from the main line, I will have, indeed, V1 minus D3 drop. And the battery is charging through D1. When the power is cut off, I will have the battery voltage at the output, through D2.

Comment: @Dorian Indeed, the voltage of the output will be regulated with a DC-DC converter to 12V.

Comment: Ok I see it now.

Comment: The maximum differential voltage is stated to 5V in the datasheet, the other current paths from IN- through base - collector junction to Vref seems safe for such a low voltage.